# JUnit @Theory : is there a way to throw meaningful exception?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit-theory

I tried Junit @Theory test style recently : it's a really efficient way of testing. However, i not pleased with the exception that are thrown when a test fails. Example :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.DataPoint;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theory;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TheoryAndExceptionTest {

    @DataPoint
    public static String yesDataPoint = "yes";

    @Theory
    public void sayNo(final String say) {
        assertEquals("no",say);
    }
}
```

I expect this test to throw a **descriptive** exception, but instead of getting something like :

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<'[no]'> but was:<'[yes]'>
```

... I get this :

```
org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: sayNo(yes) at
....
[23 lines  of useless stack trace cut]
...
Caused by: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<'[no]'> but was:<'[yes]'>
....
```

Is there a way to get rid of the 24 first lines that tell nothing about **my**test, except that yesDataPoint @DataPoint causes the failure ? That's an information i need, to know what is failing, but i really would like to know *how* it fails on the same time.

**[edited]**

I replaced org.fest.assertions usage by classic org.junit.Assert.assertEquals, to avoid confusion. 
Additionally, it's not related either with Eclipse : that long (useless/confusing) stack trace is what you get too when you run and fail a @Theory from the command line.

Comment: How are you getting these 23 lines before the "reaction on source"? In Eclipse for getting them from Failure Trace View, I have do go to the "reaction on source" you are looking for, "copy trace" , insert it somewhere and only then I can see all these lines.

Comment: @Gangnus Eclipse filters out a lot of the stacktrace. Look in Workspace->Preferences->Java->JUnit. Which is why you don't see them in Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I already have them filtered away. What I say, I need to do something to see these extra lines. But thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a problem with catching the [ComparisonFailure](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/ComparisonFailure.html) and printing the GetMessage() of it?

```
public void sayNo(final String say) {
    try {
        assertThat(say).isEqualTo("no");
    }catch(ComparisonFailure e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage);
    }
}
```

Apologies if there is something I misunderstand.

Edit: ComparisonFailure also has getExpected() and getActual() methods that you can invoke if you are looking for certain formatting.

Comment: Catching exception in a test is really bad ... and it's worse when you do it to System.out.println reason of failure ;)

Comment: @Oliver ok, sorry. Just trying to learn here. Don't all uncaught exceptions print the stack trace? (My ignorance is due to only just now learning about unit testing)

Answer (score 0):

You have a very strange library. You have a strange syntax for assertThat. I would propose:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class TheoryAndExceptionTest {

    @DataPoint
    public static String yesDataPoint = "yes";

    @Theory
    public void sayNo(final String say) {

        assertThat(say,is("no"));
    }

    @Test
    public void yesNo() {
        assertEquals("must be equal, ", "yes","no");
    }
}
```

Then you'll have:

```
org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: sayNo(yesDataPoint)
....

Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "no"
     got: "yes"
```

As for assertEqual you are right, it seems it won't help in Theories.
Only for the @Test:

```
    org.junit.ComparisonFailure: must be equal,  expected:<[yes]> but was:<[no]>
```

## An addition:

You can also use

```
assertThat("must be equal, ", say,is("no"));
```

Than you'll have the output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: must be equal, 
Expected: is "no"
     got: "yes"
```

As for filtering extra lines, use Failure Trace View in Eclipse.

Comment: Fest assert is not the problem : using assertEqual(msg, expected, actual) only change the root cause (Caused by: junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: ... instead of org.junit.ComparisonFailure)

Comment: Strange syntax for assertThat comes from Fluent assertion (http://bit.ly/MRtJpl), you should give it at try :)

Comment: My Juno Eclipse refuses to understand your code. Please, show there all imports you use.

Comment: Have you noticed, that org.fest.assertions do not belong to junit (https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x/wiki/One-minute-starting-guide)? It can be used by JUnit, but doesn't belong to it. Try JUnit assertThat.

Comment: I have tried your assertThat from org.fest. Here is the problem specified - assertThat from org.fest really doesn't give the obviously necessary info in the Failure Trace, in contrast to assertThat and assertEquals from JUnit

Comment: Fest Assert is written as wrapper around Junit assertions in order to write fluent tests. No, that's not the problem ;) However, I'll edit my example to avoid confusion (btw thank you for taking time to find a solution!)

Comment: What Eclipse View are you looking at? Have you looked at Failure Trace? I mean, in the case of hamcrest or JUnit assertions.