# ParameterizedAssertionError using EasyTest when test case fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I wanted to try EasyTest to get input parameters from a CSV and found the following, nicely written, example in a blog posted here:

http://gpcmol.blogspot.com/2013/06/easytest-unit-testing-with-externalized.html

If I follow the example it runs beautifully giving me a nice PDF output as advertised.

However if I cause a test case failure, by changing the last line of input from ",9,-12" to ",9,-13", I no longer get PDF output and get 2 failures rather than one.

The first failure is the correct assertion that the test case fails.  The second failure is the following exception:

```
<testcase name="classMethod" classname="TransformCelciusTest" time="0.0">
    <failure message="org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: testToCelsiusConverter(TestInfo [testClass=org.junit.runners.model.TestClass@90bb3e6, dataLoader=org.easetech.easytest.loader.CSVDataLoader@5f4fc5ad, filePaths=[data/temperatureConversionData.csv], methodName=testToCelsiusConverter])" type="org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError">org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: testToCelsiusConverter(TestInfo [testClass=org.junit.runners.model.TestClass@90bb3e6, dataLoader=org.easetech.easytest.loader.CSVDataLoader@5f4fc5ad, filePaths=[data/temperatureConversionData.csv], methodName=testToCelsiusConverter])
    at org.easetech.easytest.util.RunAftersWithOutputData.writeData(RunAftersWithOutputData.java:157)
    at org.easetech.easytest.util.RunAftersWithOutputData.evaluate(RunAftersWithOutputData.java:133)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.easetech.easytest.loader.CSVDataLoader.writeDataToCSV(CSVDataLoader.java:364)
    at org.easetech.easytest.loader.CSVDataLoader.writeData(CSVDataLoader.java:180)
    at org.easetech.easytest.util.RunAftersWithOutputData.writeData(RunAftersWithOutputData.java:154)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.easetech.easytest.loader.CSVDataLoader.writeOutputData(CSVDataLoader.java:382)
    at org.easetech.easytest.loader.CSVDataLoader.writeDataToCSV(CSVDataLoader.java:347)
    ... 29 more
</failure>
  </testcase>
```

Anybody understand how to modify the example so that it properly completes without the ParameterizedAssertionError exception so that the test case failure can be properly reported in the output (PDF)?

I think this is related:
[JUnit @Theory : is there a way to throw meaningful exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751161/junit-theory-is-there-a-way-to-throw-meaningful-exception)

Comment: Note: Using easytest-core 1.3.1.  Is this a bug in EasyTest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the scenario with EasyTest Core 1.3.1 library and indeed it is an issue(infact a bug) in EasyTest 1.3.1. Specifically there is a NullPointerException in CSVDataLoader because it is expecting the test Duration value but its not present because of test failure. I have to see whats the best solution for this problem. I will keep you posted of the solution. In the mean time, you could try the Excel and XML Data loader. Or if you want a quick solution, you can copy paste the CSVDataLoader and override the line 364 of CSVDataLoader such that it checks if DURATIOn is present and only then call toString on it. Then you can use this Loader as Custom loader in the @DataLoader annotation.

Thanks,
Anuj Kumar

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  Indeed using Excel (temperatureConversionData.xls) worked, and is an easy workaround.